# how to identity a person when login with oauth2

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0

In OAuth1.0,the access_token and the access_secret is unique for every user in the third party system(like facebook).so when i login by Facebook,it returns me the access_token and access_secret,i can register a user in my site and login.

In OAuth 2.0,it only returns access_token,and expires time.and the access_token may expire after several days. how to identify a person?(or must i request it's api to save the uid of facebook to reach this goal)?

Answer (score 1):

Keeping track of users is completely in your responsibility and not part of OAuth. OAuth just specifies how you can get access using an Access Token to a provider API.

So yes, you have to fetch the user info from Facebook to get the unique ID. ;)

Comment: you mean in OAuth1.0 i try to identify person with token and secret is not recommended.

Comment: Well, at least they were not [intended for this](http://oauth.net/core/1.0/#access_grant), but for signing requests. If a user logs out and back in you get new tokens and can't know that this is the same user. For most purposes you want to know that and therefore use the ID of the user.